# Wrong nationality on US visa

Tags: usa, visa

I just noticed that the US embassy put the wrong nationality on my (K1) visa. GRBR (where I live) instead of Italy (my actual nationality). It was their mistake, all my documents are correct. What should I do?

The US embassy (in London) does not take phone calls, they only reply to communications sent through their website and they take 3-5 days to reply.

I already booked the trip, the wedding and the honeymoon.

What happens if I arrive at the point of entry, NY in my case, with this visa? Will they send me back? Can I ask them to fix it when I'm in the US?

Thanks.

Comment: "What you should do" probably depends somewhat on when you plan to travel.  When do you plan to travel?  (That said, if you show up with that visa, I suspect the immigration officer will most likely recognize that the State Department has made a clerical error that should not affect you or the validity of your visa.)

Comment: I leave on Monday and the US embassy is closed for bank holiday on Friday and Monday. I managed to get through with a phone call. The consulate claim I should not have any problems, they sent me an email briefly explaining my case that I can print out and show since they will be closed so can't be called by the immigration officer to verify. Worst case scenario I'll wait until 3 in the morning when the embassy re-opens..

Comment: Yikes! Try calling the embassy?

Comment: Are the rest of your details on the visa correct? I would expect that if you show a passport with the correct number, but a wrong nationality, that will be enough to convince immigration there was an error, especially with the email from the consulate saying that.

Comment: Everything else both on the passport and the visa was correct. The only mistake was the nationality on the visa (sticker on the passport). Not sure whether the immigration officers noticed but I went through without problems.

Comment: What happened than ,did you travel